# How to Scale Metabolic rate and drug dosage according to Mass?

Tags: zoology, metabolism, herpetology, allometry

I was reading a book "Biology and evolution of Crocodilians" by Gordon Grigg and David Kirshner.

And I can't understand the part about metabolic scaling no matter which method I tried I can't get the same result as the one in the book.
(Box 1.2 and Box 7.1)

Box 1.2
It is about Lolong immobilization and dosage which has example of 0.5mg for 40kg Croc scaling to 2.4mg for 1075kg Lolong instead of 13mg, however no matter which method I tried I could not get the same number. (exponent for crocodilians is 0.829)
When I tried
(0.5/(40^0.829))×(1075^0.829) for Box 1.2 I got 7.65420145365 instead of 2.4

For Box 7.1
It gave example of 0.1kg to 10 kg mammal oxygen consumption scaling from 116ml/h in 0.1kg animals to 3483 in 10kg animals (as oppose to 11600 ml/h.) (exponent for mammals here use 0.738)

I tried (116/(0.1^0.738))×(10^0.738)
Which get 3471.02697847
Instead of 3483.

I have no background in science at all so it is likely I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome user71055. We've an international community here many of whom simply won't have access to that particular textbook. Please quote the relevant text in the body of your question, then show what attempt you've  made to understand it (show your workings). Please also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: 3471 and 3483 are the same number unless you have at least 3 significant digits of precision in all your estimates.

Comment: When I tried the
 (0.5/(40^0.829))×(1075^0.829) for Box 1.2 I still can't get 2.4 but instead got 7.65420145365